# Mule 3 to Mule 4 error handling queries for error types and http status

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I am migrating an error handling file from Mule 3 to Mule 4 using Anypoint Studio 7.

My queries are:

- How would I do I now do this check as I cannot see the same information in the exception message? `#[exception.causedBy(org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException)]"`
- Where do I find the http.status property now?  I can see it as a variable when it is 200 but when the error is thrown it seems to disappear and cannot locate it in the message
- Where can I find a list of error handling types?

The error handling types I'm particularly interested in are below but no idea if that is the correct value for the error type:

```
HTTP:BAD_REQUEST
HTTP:UNAUTHORIZED
HTTP:FORBIDDEN
HTTP:RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND
HTTP:METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
HTTP:NOT_ACCEPTABLE
HTTP:CONFLICT
HTTP:UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE
HTTP:INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
HTTP:BAD_GATEWAY
```

Snippet of the Mule 3 code I am migrating is below and I think it was based on a template:

```
<choice-exception-strategy name="global-exception-strategy">    
    <catch-exception-strategy when="#[exception.causedBy(org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException)]" doc:name="Caused By (org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException)">
        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status'] == 401]">
                <set-variable variableName="errorMessage" value="Upstream service did not authorize the request." doc:name="Set Error Message"/>
                <flow-ref name="global-bad-gateway-response-sub-flow" doc:name="Bad Gateway Response"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <set-variable variableName="errorMessage" value="Upstream service internal error." doc:name="Set Error Message"/>
                <flow-ref name="global-bad-gateway-response-sub-flow" doc:name="Bad Gateway Response"/>                
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </catch-exception-strategy>
</choice-exception-strategy>        

<sub-flow name="global-bad-gateway-response-sub-flow">
    <set-property propertyName="http.status" value="401" doc:name="Set Status"/>
    <set-payload value="UNAUTHORIZED" doc:name="Set Error Code" mimeType="application/java"/>
    <flow-ref name="global-prepare-error-response-sub-flow" doc:name="Prepare Error Response"/>
</sub-flow>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use these kind of check

```
#[contains(error.description,'internal server error (500).')]
```

Answer (score 0):

in Mule 4 http status code for error response located here
#[error.errorMessage.attributes['statusCode']]

Comment: Can you expand your answer to include answers to all the queries?